# php 5.3.3 and Magento 1.7 (vulnerable?)

Tags: magento-1.7, php, magento-1, security

I need some advice,

Is it safe to run php 5.3.3 on Magento 1.7.0.2.? How critically important to update to higher php? **Given that all latest patches are installed on Magento.**
I am concerned about **updating to 5.4 or higher since I am not sure about compatibility.**
What is the suggested php version for 1.7.0.2 ?

Please add your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to run PHP 5.3 - it does not get security fixes for over two years already. Even for PHP 5.5, new security issues are not fixed anymore. So to be on the safe side regarding your PHP version, you need to have at least PHP 5.6

The problem with Magento 1.7 is though that it is not compatible with newer PHP versions.

- For PHP 5.4 compatibility there is a patch available (targeting Magento 1.6.0.0-1.8.0.0): https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?icid=BLOG_php54_downloadpage#download252
- PHP 5.5 compatibility has been added in 1.9.1.0
- PHP 5.6 compatibility has been added in 1.9.3.0
- PHP 7.0 compatibility is only available through a community extension: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

That leaves you with a "safe" update (in the sense of "it should work") to PHP 5.4 only, which is only a slight improvement of your status quo.

However, there are very little actual issues with PHP 5.6 on older Magento versions. We run a CE 1.8.1.0 store on PHP 5.6 without trouble. Your milage may vary depending on installed extensions and used features.

### So my suggestion is:

- update to latest PHP 5.6
- test, test, test
- patch incompatibilities yourself, based on the PHP migration guides: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php

Comment: Great, I will try out 5.6 on 1.7.0.2 and see how it goes... Do you think its important to install PHP 5.4 patch, if I plan to use 5.6 PHP ?

Comment: @Icon yes, that's essential if you update to anything above 5.3

Comment: I really appreciate your responses! I am wondering, if its is so essential to have latest PHP versions, why don't magento do anything about it? Updating from 1.7- 1.9 version is a huge problem just to have full PHP compatibility.

Comment: That's a good question and unfortunately I don't have a satisfying answer for it. Apparently they don't consider compatibility with a secure PHP version a critical security fix, so they don't supply it for old versions (unlike Magento related security fixes)

Answer (score 0):

Well, **PHP 5.3 stopped receiving security fixes in 2014** so I highly suggest you upgrade to at least the last supported version of PHP which is 5.6 because you're vulnerable to attacks right now: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: To be exact, which latest version of php supports magetnto 1.7.0.2  to be safe from errors?

Comment: @Icon PHP 5.6 ;)

Comment: I wish that were true, but I am not aware of any patches to add 5.6 compatibility to Magento 1.7